# Is there a better way of coping with Swift's nested "if let" "pyramid of doom?"

Tags: xcode, swift, if-statement, option-type, let

Is there a better way of dealing with a chain of optional properties than nested **if let** statements? I have been advised to use if lets when examining optional properties, which makes sense as it deals with them at compile time rather than run time, but it looks like utter madness! Is there is a better way?

Here is the current "pyramid of doom" I have ended up with, as an example:

```
( users: [ JSONValue ]? ) in

if let jsonValue: JSONValue = users?[ 0 ]
{
    if let json: Dictionary< String, JSONValue > = jsonValue.object
    {
        if let userIDValue: JSONValue = json[ "id" ]
        {
            let userID: String = String( Int( userIDValue.double! ) )
            println( userID )
        }
    }
}
```

**Post-script**

Airspeed Velocity's answer below is the right answer, but you will need Swift 1.2 to use multiple lets separated by commas as he suggests, which only currently runs in XCode 6.3, which is in beta.

Comment: Well this is the infamous 'pyramid of doom' problem, which is finally resolved in an elegant way in Swift 1.2. You can read [more about it here](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As commenters have said, Swift 1.2 now has multiple-let syntax:

```
if let jsonValue = users?.first,
       json = jsonValue.object,
       userIDValue = json[ "id" ],
       doubleID = userIDValue.double,
       userID = doubleID.map({ String(Int(doubleID))})
{
    println( userID )
}
```

That said, in this instance it looks like you could might be able to do it all via optional chaining in 1.1, depending on what your objects are:

```
if let userID = users?.first?.object?["id"]?.double.map({String(Int($0))}) {

    println(userID)

}
```

Note, much better to use `first` (if this is an array) rather than `[0]`, to account for the possibility the array is empty.  And map on the `double` rather than `!` (which would blow up if the value is not double-able).

Comment: Thanks Airspeed velocity. However, the code snippet you posted is throwing "Expected '{' after 'if' condition". Am I perhaps using a older version of Swift here? And I am specifically trying to avoid optional chaining, thanks. MJB.

Comment: I see. I need the XCode 6.3 beta. I'll run along and get that, thanks guys.

Comment: Airspeed Velocity: I notice these lets are all weakly typed. Is that normal/OK? I come from a culture of strongly typing as much as possible, ideally everything. Is that less important to the Swift crowd?

Comment: All variables in Swift are strongly typed, but their type can be “inferred”.  For example, if you write `let i = 1`, then `i` will be an `Int`, but you don’t need to explicitly write `i: Int` – Swift will figure it out from the type of the right-hand side.  Then if you write `let j = i`, `j` will also be an `Int`.  But if you write `let k = i + 1.5` you will get an error, "binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and ‘Double'"

Comment: The idea is that the explicit typing is frequently clutter that is obvious from the context but gets in the way of the code being easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE for Swift-3** : The syntax has changed :

```
if let jsonValue = users?.first,
       let json = jsonValue.object,
       let userIDValue = json[ "id" ],
       let doubleID = userIDValue.double,
       let userID = doubleID.map({ String(Int(doubleID))})
{
    println( userID )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 2**, we have the `guard` statement.

Instead of:

```
func myFunc(myOptional: Type?) {
  if let object = myOptional! {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can do it like this:

```
func myFunc(myOptional: Type?) {
  guard array.first else { return }
}
```

Check http://nshipster.com/guard-and-defer/ from NSHipster.